# Merge two/more image in Android(widget)

Tags: java, android, image, merge, widget

Trying to create a widget with custom fonts, but read that widget doesn't support custom font.

I thought that I could create 10 png's for every number(0-10, not going to use abc ect).

By using that method I need to create several imageviews... that seems a waste of views.

So if I want to have the number 1337 I need 4 ImageViews. Isn't there a way to merge the png's (R.drawable), so I get a Bitmap or something and only one 1 ImageView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your own custom drawable (`extends Drawable`) where you pass the parameter (i.e. number) you want to draw.
You would be overriding the

```
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
   ....
   // use this to place another bitmap, i.e. number images, onto the canvas
   canvas.drawBitmap(..,..,..);  
   ...
}
```

method and merge the images into one drawable, that you then apply to your one single imageview.